# Make "If" return a comment

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm wondering if there is a way to show up a comment if two cells have different values eg "=if(A1=B1, "show a comment", "show a comment"), Thanks

Comment: You can use conditional formatting to conditionally show formatting -- including icons/indicators  -- but not text as far as I know.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: You can do this from VBA: Sheet1.Range("B1").AddComment ("Comment")

Comment: So just like this: =if(A1=B1, "", "show a comment") or reverse the logic: =if(A1<>B1, "show a comment", "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Function if_then_comment(criteria, ifTrueString As String, _
    ifTrueComment As String, ifFalseString As String, ifFalseComment As String)
    
    Dim calcDefault
    Application.Volatile
    calcDefault = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' => disable events
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With Application.ThisCell
        If criteria Then
            if_then_comment = ifTrueString
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment (ifTrueComment)
        Else
            if_then_comment = ifFalseString
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment (ifFalseComment)
        End If
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.Calculation = calcDefault
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' => enable events
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
   Try the function below
  =IF(A1>B1,"comment",IF(A1<B1,"comment"))
```

Comment: How does this show a comment?

Comment: Pls try the function before downvoting, it checks if the values to the left is greater than that on the right,then shows a comment, then it checks if the value to the left is less than the values to the right, then it shows a comment. So you can write same comment for the two scenerios. if both values are not the same, i.e <> is the same has either values greater or less than the other.

Comment: I tried your code. And as far as I can see, the code shows the comment text in the cell, but it doesn't show it as a comment (red triangle + comment box). Please check the answer by simple-solution to see what I mean.

Comment: The OP Wrote, and i quote "I'm wondering if there is a way to show up a comment if two cells have different values eg "=if(A1=B1, "show a comment", "show a comment"), Thanks", so my answer is tailored towards the question which is how to alter the function "=if(A1=B1, "show a comment", "show a comment")" to work when both columns are not the same.

Comment: Exactly: They asked to show a **comment**. And they accepted the other answer which shows a comment.

Comment: To show a comment  as written by the OP is in double quotes, hence it can be taken by a reader to mean a text or string message and not to show a comment.